# Why when changing the points radius size it's working too slow?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a new class top:

```
private Random r = new Random();
public int numberOfPoints = 100;
public Bitmap bmpWithPoints;
```

Then in the class Initi method:

```
public void Init()
        {            
                bmpWithPoints = GetBitmapWithEllipses(1.0f);
        }
```

Then then method GetBitmapWithEllipses:

```
private Bitmap GetBitmapWithEllipses(float radius)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            Random r = new Random();

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                    g.Clear(Color.Black);
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    List<RectangleF> rects = new List<RectangleF>();
                    rects.Add(new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 0));

                    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfPoints; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < numberOfPoints; y++)
                        {
                            Color c = Color.FromArgb(
                                r.Next(0, 256),
                                r.Next(0, 256),
                                r.Next(0, 256));

                            PointF p = new PointF(r.Next(bmp.Width), r.Next(bmp.Height));
                            RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(p, new SizeF(radius * 2, radius * 2));

                            if (!rects.Any(tmp => tmp.IntersectsWith(rect)))
                            {
                                rects.Add(rect);
                                g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(c), rect);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                y--;
                            }
                        }
                    }                
            }

            return bmp;
        }
```

In Form1 top and constructor:

```
DopplerEffect de = new DopplerEffect();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            de.bmpWithPoints = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            de.numberOfPoints = 50;
            de.Init();
        }
```

Before i had a problem the method GetBitmapWithEllipses was slow because when setting the number of points to 50. Now this part is working fast but now when changing the radius size to 5.0f or 10.0f it's very slow.

When i set the number of points to 10 or 20 or 50 in Form1 in the line:

```
de.numberOfPoints = 50;
```

The method GetBitmapWithEllipses in the class will work fast.
But if i change in the class the radius size of the points each point for example to 1.0f it will work fast. But if i set the number of points to 50 and change the radius size to 10.0f for example the method GetBitmapWithEllipses will work very slow. Even to 5.0f

Is there any way to make it work fast also when changing the radius size for each point ?

Comment: You randomly create circles in the loop and if the created circles has an overlap with previous created ellipses you step the loop backward. When the radios grows the chance of overlap increases, so you step backward more and the loop take more long to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You randomly create circles in the loop and if the new created circle has an overlap with previous created circles you step the loop backward.

When the radios grows the chance of overlap increases, so you step backward more and the loop takes too long to finish. In fact there is no guarantee for your loop to even finish!

You can comment the code which checks for overlap and the code which makes the loop step backward, then you will have a fast result:

```
//if (!rects.Any(tmp => tmp.IntersectsWith(rect)))
//{
//    rects.Add(rect);
      g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(c), rect);
//}
//else
//{
//    y--;
//}
```

Comment: How important is to check for overlap ?

Comment: I don't have any idea about the goal of creating such effect. So you should know better :)